# Reorganization failed Genexus

Tags: genexus

This KB is a conversion from Evolution X version 1. I'm using Genexus 16, Java, SQL Server, So trying to Build an import file XPZ, I have errors, I tried changing the option Build Proces -> Advanced, -> "-nogui -ignoreresume " and Rebuil ALL, but I'm still having the same errors.

Any idea what can I do?

```
Success: Default (Java Web) Generation
========== Reorganization started ==========
"C:\Models\gx16\CWP_10.S\JavaModel\web\callmake.bat" "C:\Models\gx16\CWP_10.S\JavaModel\web\GXJMake.exe" "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\javac.exe" Reorganization  options: -J-Xmx1024m
GeneXus Java Make v1.0
reorg.java:146: error: cannot find symbol
      Application.commitDataStores(context, remoteHandle, pr_default, "reorg");
                 ^
  symbol:   method commitDataStores(ModelContext,int,IDataStoreProvider,String)
  location: class Application
reorg.java:149: error: cannot find symbol
      Application.commitDataStores(context, remoteHandle, pr_default, "reorg");
                 ^
  symbol:   method commitDataStores(ModelContext,int,IDataStoreProvider,String)
  location: class Application
Reorganization.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
      setReorgProcedure(r);
      ^
  symbol:   method setReorgProcedure(reorg)
  location: class Reorganization
jbf019conversion.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
         Application.getSmartCacheProvider(remoteHandle).setUpdated("GXA1331") ;
                    ^
  symbol:   method getSmartCacheProvider(int)
  location: class Application
4 errors
failed ( error code=1)
Build failed.
Failed: Reorganization
error: Error in reorganization
Failed: Rebuild All
```

**After updated gxclassR.zip and building again:**

```
Success: Database Impact Analysis
Generating Resources...Success
========== Default (Java Web) Generation started ==========
Generating to JavaModel\web\reorg.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\ReorganizationScript.txt
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomainboolean.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomainfckeditormodes.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomainfckeditorobjectinterface.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomaingoogletableformatter.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomainheadertype.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomaink2baftertrnnavigation.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomaink2bbtntooltip.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomaink2bhttpmethod.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomaink2bsesitem.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomaink2bstandardactivitytype.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomaink2btrnmode.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomaink2btrnreturnmode.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomainpurchaseordertype.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomainqueryvieweraggregationtype.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomainqueryvieweraxisordertype.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomainqueryvieweraxistype.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomainqueryviewercharttype.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomainqueryviewerconditionoperator.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomainqueryviewerexpandcollapse.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomainqueryviewerfiltertype.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomainqueryviewerobjecttype.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomainqueryviewerorientation.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomainqueryvieweroutputtype.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomainqueryviewerplotseries.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomainqueryviewershowdataas.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomainqueryviewershowdatalabelsin.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomainqueryviewersubtotals.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomainqueryviewertrendperiod.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomainqueryviewerxaxislabels.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxdomainticketpriority.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxrtctls.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\jbf019conversion.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\gxcfg.js
Generating to JavaModel\web\reorg.cfg
Generating to JavaModel\web\GXcfg.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\client.cfg
Generating to JavaModel\web\_COPYCLS.GEN
Generating to JavaModel\web\REORGPGM.GEN
Generating to JavaModel\web\Reorganization.java
Generating to JavaModel\web\web.xml
Generating to JavaModel\web\bld12reorg.info
Success: Default (Java Web) Generation
========== Reorganization started ==========
"C:\Models\gx16\CWP_10.S\JavaModel\web\callmake.bat" "C:\Models\gx16\CWP_10.S\JavaModel\web\GXJMake.exe" "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\javac.exe" Reorganization  options: -J-Xmx1024m
GeneXus Java Make v1.0
Build succeeded.
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java.exe"  Reorganization -nogui -ignoreresume
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLComponent.getFeatureDefault(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Boolean;
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.addRecognizedParamsAndSetDefaults(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.addCommonComponent(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.createObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.createObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.setFeature(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.enableXInclude(XmlConfiguration.java:230)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.newDocumentBuilder(XmlConfiguration.java:189)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:89)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(XmlConfigurationFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:532)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:456)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:318)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:687)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:708)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:263)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:153)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:602)
    at com.genexus.diagnostics.core.provider.Log4J2Logger.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.genexus.diagnostics.core.LogManager.getLogger(Unknown Source)
    at com.genexus.Application.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.genexus.GXReorganization.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Reorganization.<init>(Reorganization.java:24)
    at Reorganization.main(Reorganization.java:19)
Failed: Reorganization
error: Error in reorganization
Failed: Build main
```

Comment: It seems you are using the wrong version of gxclasses. Check your classpath in Genexus preferences and ensure they are pointing to your GX version.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @gusbro , I updated gxclassR.zip and I think that helps, but still have errors.

Comment: @DerimarGray It seems you still have some classpath issues. Different versions of the same third party library which may not be compatible with current requirements.

Comment: You may move away (backup+delete) `JavaModel` then try the reorganization so GX will update all the resources it currently needs.